# Gerar histograma em django

Tags: python, django, histograma

Estou tentando gerar um histograma em *Django* para um projeto que desenvolvi. O código costuma gerar o histograma sem dificuldades na primeira tentativa, contudo, quando tento novamente, ele me retorna o seguinte erro:

> RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop.

Como posso corrigir este erro? 
Segue abaixo o código:

```
def gerador_de_histograma():
    y_axis = definir_valores_das_classes_histograma()
    x_axis = range(len(limite_corte_entre_classes))
    width_n = 0.8
    bar_color = 'green'

    bar = plt.bar(x_axis, y_axis, width=width_n, color=bar_color, align="center", linewidth=10)
    plt.xticks(x_axis, gerador_de_nomes_para_labels(limite_corte_entre_classes))
    return plt
    # plt.show()
    # plt.save("histograma.png")



def show_histogram(request):
    histogram = gerador_de_histograma()
    return render(request, 'city/histogram.html',{'histogram': histogram})
```

Comment: que biblioteca você está usando para gerar os gráficos?

Comment: Estou usando a mathplotlib